# How to know that Groovy console window has been closed

Tags: java, grails, groovy, groovy-console

I am launching groovy console window in run time through below code. Suppose user has closed the groovy console window. I want to detect closing of window in my program.

```
import groovy.ui.Console
public class TestGroovyConsole{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int x = 5;
        Console console = new Console();
        console.setVariable("x",x);// to make x available in console
        console.run(); // to launch console
    }

}
```

Please suggest possible solution. does groovy provide any method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add a `WindowAdapter`:

```
import groovy.ui.Console
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter

class TestGroovyConsole{
    static main(args){
        int x = 5
        Console console = new Console()
        console.setVariable("x",x) // to make x available in console
        console.run() // to launch console
        console.frame.addWindowListener([windowClosing: { e -> println "Console closing" }] as WindowAdapter)
    }
}
```